# How to make child div scrollable when it exceeds parent height?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 child divs nested in a parent div in row-column pattern: the parent is a column, and the children are rows.[image]

The upper child div is of variable height, but is guaranteed to be less than the height of the parent div.

The lower child div is also of variable height.  In some cases, the heights of the child divs will make the lower child div exceed the parent.  In this case, I need to make the lower div scrollable. Note that I want only the lower div to be scrollable, not the whole parent div.

How do I handle this?

See attached jsfiddle for case example: http://jsfiddle.net/0yxnaywu/5/

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        hello world filler
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        this div should overflow and scroll down
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.parent {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.child1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.child2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: you will need to add scroller for parent http://jsfiddle.net/0yxnaywu/1/

Comment: So this makes the whole parent div scrollable, I'd like only the lower child div to be scrollable.

Comment: Not positive, but I think you'll have to use some javascript. Overflow only works when you give it a value to overflow when greater than. Your value is relative to how big the top is, which I think you'll need to grab to then calculate.

Comment: Check my answer for an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overflow only works when you give it a value to overflow when greater than. Your value is relative to how big the top is, so using jQuery, grab that value then subtract from the parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".child2").css("max-height", ($(".parent").height()-$(".child1").height()));
});
```

and add `overflow`'s to the children

```css
.child1 {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child2 {
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m9goxrbk/

Comment: Makes sense! Was wondering if this was possible without Javascript, but even so I think this solution is elegant. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer at the time, but is out of date now.

Answer (score 134):

Because this post is still ranking very high in Google, I'd like to post a better solution using flexbox. Actually this is very simple.
Use **display: flex**, **flex-direction: column** and **overflow: hidden** for parent and **overflow-y: auto** for child.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scrollable-child {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Here's the pen:
https://codepen.io/pawelsas/pen/vdwjpj

Comment: it also works without the ```overflow: hidden;``` of the *.wrapper*

Comment: Thanks for the 2018 answer, in my case I had to also declare `flex: 1` on the `.wrapper` to fill the screen space

Comment: I mean your rationale to post a better solution because the ranking is good on google is not justified but the solution works for me

Answer (score 7):

### When you have nested child divs

This solution is to scroll the child div that overflows instead of scrolling the entire parent when divs are nested.

> Refer to the attached image. The expected behavior is on the right side ✅

Add the below CSS to all the parent divs ( `Parent`, `Child1`, `Child2` ) that need to pass the scroll bar down to the scrollable child. ( flex column makes the divs take the available height )

```css
.all-parents {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

The target element that overflows ( `Child 3` ) should be assigned `overflow: auto` to enable scrolling.

```css
.element-that-overflows {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

**Note:** You need to specify a fixed height for the topmost parent ( `Parent` ) to make the child scroll, else the Parent scrolls.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

---

[Open in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9v7etb?file=src%2Fstyle.css,src%2FApp.js)

[image: Image showing difference between parent having the scroll and the child having the scroll when child overflows on left and right respectively]

Answer (score 4):

Use [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property:

```
.parent {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0yxnaywu/2/)

*EDIT:*

if you want only second div to be scrollable, you need to change it height to `30px` so `child1` and `child2` will exactly fit the parent `height` and add `overflow` property there:

```
.parent {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.child1 {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: red;
}

.child2 {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0yxnaywu/3/)

Comment: They want only child div 2 to become scrollable, not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

set child to `overflow:scroll` and ALL its parents to `overflow:hidden`