# Nested child div not scrollable when container div is fixed

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a container div (modal) that is set to `position: fixed` (absolute is not an option for my purpose). Inside of this container I have two columns. One of these columns contains tab buttons with below them some content or a form. This content (only the content, not the tabs) should be scrollable but I can't figure out how.

The height of the tabs can change so the solution can't contain a fixed height for the tab bar.

I've tried to make the whole column scrollable first by setting the column to `position: relative`, `min-height: 100%` and `overflow-y: scroll` but this first try didn't even work.

[Codepen with basic setup](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzKMPw)

**EDIT**

Not a duplicate of [How to make child div scrollable when it exceeds parent height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784727/how-to-make-child-div-scrollable-when-it-exceeds-parent-height)

- I'm working inside a fixed container
- I'm working with flexible heights
- Trying to achieve a css only solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make child div scrollable when it exceeds parent height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784727/how-to-make-child-div-scrollable-when-it-exceeds-parent-height)

Answer (score 3):

This issue is occurring because you are not declaring "max-height" to container ".details-column".

Try below CSS :

> .content{
>     max-height: 400px;
>     overflow-y: auto; 
>   }

Note: You have to set fixed height or fixed max-height of the container otherwise container won't know when it has to scroll data.

Comment: Thanks, finally someone that explains his answer. I will calculate the max-height with some JS but I've got another problem using your solution. The width/x-axis becomes scrollable too. See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYLQOX You can see that the input fields are not fully shown

Comment: Glad to know! You are not using "Box-sizing" in your CSS which included Padding without increasing width of element. You can use any snippet from these two : 1) *{box-sizing: border-box;} or 2) form input {width: 99%;}. I Hope it will help you. Please let me know if you needed fiddle for same.

Answer (score 1):

**Excerpt from W3School**:

> The overflow property only works for block elements with a specified
>   height.

but since you've flexible height element doesn't know when to overflow as it will just keep on growing.

you'll most likely have to define a height or max-height or even use JS to calculate height, other suggestion i can make is to play around with `white-space` property as well as calc() for height.

**Edit:**
*Here is a very good source to help you understand overflows:* https://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Good Luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will use JS to calculate the height but using the overflow-y property leads to an x-scroll as well. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYLQOX

Comment: That's because you'll explicitly have to tell the browser that the `overflow-x` needs to be hidden, currently both `x & y` are set to scroll, try something like this:

`overflow: hidden;`  hide the overflow and then set the y to scroll
`overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqYzbM The x-scroll is gone but the content exceeds the width of the form. You can see it on the input boxes. The right border isn't visible

Comment: in your case and in that specific pen, I fixed the issue by adding: `input { box-sizing: border-box;}` but I'd suggest you to read https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp to understand the concept, which you might already be aware of.

Comment: Yea, in my project I've got a reset css file so the problem will be specific to this pen. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

By applying following css your div will be scrollable.

```
.content{
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

Comment: It's not: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPedzJ. Also, I can't work with fixed heights. I can't know if the height of the content is 80%.

Answer (score -1):

this is because there is not much content to make it scroll.. put some content and try.. check below link

```
overflow-y: auto
```

add this to the modal class. thanks

https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/mvbpJV`99`

Comment: The form inside the modal should be scrollable, not the actual page with lorem ipsum

Comment: Did you read my question? I want the form to be scrollable. Not the complete modal or both columns.